# How to get a query to pass through the script again?

Tags: powershell, menu

This might be a simple question but how do you get a PS query to pass through your script after completion or error. I want the script to pass through the following example.

```
$menu = read-host -prompt "example"

if ($menu -eq 1) {$example1 = read-host -prompt "example"}
if ($example1 -eq 1) {
  Write-Host "Completed"
  Clear-History
}
```

I then want the script after it is completed to start at `$menu` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `do..while` loop. This will execute until you populate `$menu` with <kbd>q</kbd>:

```
do {
  $menu = read-host -prompt "example"

  if ($menu -eq 1) {
    $example1 = read-host -prompt "example"
    if ($example1 -eq 1) {
      Write-Host "Completed"
      clear-history
    }
  }

} while ($menu -ine 'q')
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to use a `while($true)` loop. Write your script logic as a function and call it on a loop that doesn't terminate. Like so,

```
function doStuff {
    # Perform actual work here
}
# Calls doStuff again and again forever as soon as it is finished
while($true) { doStuff }
```